# Angular devextreme style dxi-column

Tags: javascript, css, angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I need to make one column in a Datagrid to have a pointer cursor but any styling does not change everything. I've tried using the dxi-column selector and also using a class. Both with and `without::ng-deep`.

Any ideas or solutions?

```
<dxi-column dataField="companyDetails.name" caption="Company">
    </dxi-column>
```

I have started using the template but I can't get the wrapper to filling out the cell

```
::ng-deep .dx-template-wrapper {
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: inline styles also have no effect whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `cssClass` property of `column`.

[Here's the docs for it](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#cssClass)

Something like:

**component.ts**

```
<dxi-column dataField="companyDetails.name" caption="Company" cssClass="pointer-column">
</dxi-column>
```

**component.scss**

```
::ng-deep pointer-column {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or if you want this class to apply globally to all grids you can just add it to the `style.scss` file without any `::ng-deep` needed.
Or even better, you can have it global for certain grids only by giving them a class:

**any-component.ts**

```
<dx-data-grid
...
class="a-type-of-grid">
</dx-data-grid>
```

**style.css**

```
//anything with this class
.pointer-column {
 cursor: pointer;
}
//grids (or other elements if you want) with the 'a-type-of-grid' class 
.a-type-of-grid {

  /*Some css just for this type of grid*/

  //overwrite the global pointer-column class
  .pointer-column {
    //css you want
  }
}
```

Hope this is clear enough. :)

Comment: Thanks! This should be the accepted answer